# Set minimum product quantity by customer group

Tags: magento2

I'm using CE edition of Magento 2.3.5-p1, and I need to restrict the wholesale users and set a minimum quantity per product, I found a extension that does this by category, but I need per product.
Is it possible?

Thanks!
Best regards,
Rui Silva

EDIT:
https://marketplace.magento.com/addify-restrictorderbycustomer.html
I think I can do it with this one, creating rule for each products, but I'll test asap and then add feedback, might help someone who has the same requirements

Answer (score 1):

BSS offer a free extension https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-minimum-order-quantity-extension.html which should give you the functionaltiy you are looking for but not on a per product level.

the following extension by meetanshi will give you the functionality on a per product level https://marketplace.magento.com/meetanshi-magento-2-limit-product-quantity-per-customer.html but this is a paid module

Comment: I've checked but it only limits per customer group but the same limit for all the products right? I need to do it per product, imagine the case I have two bottles, one the minimum is 3 other is 6, with that extension I can only limit for 1 value or did I missed something?

Comment: please see my updated answer

Comment: That one defines a maximum quantity for what i've seen, i need the minimum and per customer group as well as per product. There's no problem on being paid, I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: As far as i can see there isnt one available to do that. if it was my id use the meetanshi and extend it to change it from maximum to minimum. shouldn't take too long to implement

Comment: I get it but I still have the problem that the extension applies per customer, I need per customer group, if I get it right that extension is applied like a big sale where a customer can only buy one unit of the product, if I change to minimum every customer would have that limit regardless of the group their in

Comment: you can check this module [limit quantity grouped by product](https://www.mageants.com/limit-quantity-for-grouped-products-for-magento-2.html) will works